# An exercise in Do Carmo's book-Differential geometry of curves and surfaces

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

In do Carmo's book (page 11, exercise 9), the author gives an example of $C^0$ unrectifiable curve:
 Let $\alpha: [0,1]\to \mathbb R^2$
be given as
\begin{equation*}
\left\{\begin{aligned} \left(t,
t\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{t}\right)\right),&\quad t\neq 0,\\
(0, 0),&\quad t=0.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation*}
Show, geometrically, that the arc length of the portion of the curve
corresponding to $\frac{1}{n+1}\le t \le \frac{1}{n}$ is at least
$\frac{2}{n+\frac{1}{2}}$ Use this to show that the length of the
curve in the interval $[\frac{1}{N}, 1]$ is greater than $$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2}{n+1},
$$ and thus it tends to infinity as $N\to\infty$.

I don't know how to show "geometrically". But since $\alpha(t)$ is $C^1$ when
$t\in[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$, the length can be given
\begin{align*}
\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}} \vert \alpha^\prime(t)\vert
dt=\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}
\sqrt{1+\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{t}\right)-\frac{\pi}{t}\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{t}\right)\right)^2}dt
\end{align*}
The question is how to evaluate the above integral and compare it with $\frac{2}{n+\frac{1}{2}}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you can compare it to the two sides of a triangle with "base" vertices at the points where $ t= 1/n$ and $t = 1/(n+1)$ and a third vertex halfway between then. Each of htese two sides is longer than the altitude, and I'll bet that $2/(n+1/2))$ is just twice the altitude.

Comment: Thanks, John. I choose the third vertice to be $t=\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{2}}$ and get the answer.